# VBA Excel Copying row from one sheet to other that has a specific value in it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet(Extract) with over 100 rows. I can split them up using a Case.

```
If Target.Column = 17 Then
With Target

 Select Case .Value
   Case Is = "100U"           
   Case Is = "10A6"           
   Case Is = "10BT"           
   Case Is = "10EA"           
   Case Is = "10EJ"           
   Case Is = "10LL"           
   Case Is = "10LW"           
   Case Is = "10MI"          
   Case Is = "10MN"           
   Case Is = "10MO"           
   Case Is = "10MV"           
   Case Is = "10OC"           
   Case Is = "10WI"
  Case Else

 End Select

End With

End If
```

The problem:
Then I want to copy that row And put it in another sheet.

I have premade tables where this data has to go.

My idea was...

```
Case Is = "100U" 
      ' Go to other sheet
      'Make extra row + put in data+ update position of row of the other tables that are under that table
Case Is = "10A6" 
...
```

So yeah, i searched on youtube, but is wasnt what i was looking for...
Thank you in advance

Comment: It isn't exactly clear to me what you are asking, but you might want to take a look at the `VLOOKUP` formula, and perhaps `IF`, `MATCH` and `INDEX` formulas.

Comment: Copy a row with Target.Row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...
So I first look for the row where I want to look for data in another sheet.
Next I look in the other sheet if there is data that corresponds with the word I used in the other sheet.
I made a new row and added the data from the other sheet under the specified tabel.

```
Sub Copydata()

Lastrow = Sheets("Extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrownew = Sheets("F-").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

'Geen screen refresh
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

For r = 25 To Lastrownew

        If Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 3) = "Fase" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10MO" And Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 22) = "FAX300HR" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + a).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + a).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    a = a + 1

                End If
                Next t


            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "ACF" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10MO" And Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 22) = "FA02100" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + b).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + b).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    b = b + 1

                End If
                Next t

            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "Paint" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10EA" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + c).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + c).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    c = c + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "Engine out" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10MO" And Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 11) = "ER" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + d).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + d).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    d = d + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "Interface" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10LW" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + e).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + e).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    e = e + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "Pré-dock" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + f).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + f).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    f = f + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "Bew out" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10WI" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + g).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + g).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    g = g + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "E&T out" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10EJ" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + h).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + h).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    h = h + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 4) = "Inspectie" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + i).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + i).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    i = i + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 5) = "TCTO" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10MO" And Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 11) = "SH" Then

                    Rows(r + 3 + j).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + j).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    j = j + 1

                End If
                Next t
            ElseIf Sheets("F-").Cells(r, 5) = "NDI" Then

                For t = 2 To Lastrow
                If Sheets("Extract").Cells(t, 17) = "10MN" Then
                    Rows(r + 3 + k).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    Sheets("F-").Rows(r + 2 + k).Value = Sheets("Extract").Rows(t).Value
                    k = k + 1

                End If
                Next t
        End If





Next r
'Screen refresh
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```